# Delete Firebase Real time Database Child After 1 Week

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this my view fragment from real time database 
my code working so well 
and when i add the code to delete the database child it gives  me many errors 
 i want to delete child from posts after for example 10 days 
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBNsv.png)

```
public class HomeView extends Fragment {

private View view;
private RecyclerView recentPosts;

private DatabaseReference donor_ref;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private BloodRequestAdapter restAdapter;
private List<CustomUserData> postLists;
private ProgressDialog pd;

public HomeView() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_view_fragment, container, false);
    recentPosts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyleposts);

    recentPosts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    donor_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    postLists = new ArrayList<>();

    pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setMessage("Loading");
    pd.setCancelable(true);
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    getActivity().setTitle("My First Project");

    restAdapter = new BloodRequestAdapter(postLists);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager pmLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recentPosts.setLayoutManager(pmLayout);
    recentPosts.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recentPosts.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recentPosts.setAdapter(restAdapter);

    AddPosts();
    return view;

}
private void AddPosts()
{

    Query allposts = donor_ref.child("posts");
    pd.show();
    allposts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        private DataSnapshot snapshot;

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot singlepost : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CustomUserData customUserData = singlepost.getValue(CustomUserData.class);
                    postLists.add(customUserData);
                    restAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Database Is Empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.d("User", databaseError.getMessage());

        }

    });

    }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

i tried to delete realtime database child after X day it not working also gives me many errors
here's the code for deletion

```
long cutoff = new Date().getTime()-TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(10, TimeUnit.DAYS);
Date d = new Date(cutoff );
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String old_date = `dateFormatGmt.format(new Date(cutoff));

ref2 = new Firebase("https://b-bank-39.firebaseio.com/posts/" + Date);    
ref2.child(old_date).removeValue();
```

Any Support About Modify The Code 
Thanks

Comment: what error it gives ? please post the error log

Comment: Please check the duplicate ti see how you can solve this. Instead of 24h, use 24h*10.

Comment: @Ashish Errors Appears Inside The Java File When i try to add the deletion code maybe something missing in the code itself and im not able to find it